# Why do we specify arrays size as a parameter when passing to function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters

I searched this question, most of them says the same thing. Since we only pass the arrays address in a function, compiler can not know the arrays size by looking at the address, they say. I tried to test this by using this code, and both functions gave the same results. So, how does specifying the arrays size as a function parameter help me in a practical way?. In which conditions does specifying the size help us?.

```
class ArrayTest
{
    public:
     void say(int ar[])
     {
         cout<<ar[1]<<endl;
         cout<<ar[7]<<endl;
     }

      void say(int ar[],int sizeAn)
     {
         cout<<ar[1]<<endl;
         cout<<ar[7]<<endl;
     }

};

int main()
{
    ArrayTest test;
   int anAr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   test.say(anAr);
   test.say(anAr,5);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Whether you pass the array size or not you can still access the array *out of bounds* which is *undefined behavior* and potentially causing a crash. Passing the array size tells the function where the bounds are so you can choose not to go beyond them.

Comment: This is inherited from `C` language, if you use [std::array](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) you don't need to use array size as a parameter function.

Comment: What that means is that you have no way to determine the size of an array passed to the function from inside the function, except for passing the size as a separate parameter. If you always call your function with arrays of a same known size, you can off course hardcore that size in the function. But if you want to be able to call it with arrays of different size, you need a separate parameter.

Comment: If you want to determine the number of elements in an object, use `sizeof(object) / sizeof(type)`. That's not what you asked for, but you can use that so you won't have to include the number of elements as a parameter to your functions.

Comment: @edition That won't work inside the functions because the array is passed only by a pointer to its first element. All the static size information is lost and the compiler can not deduce it.

Answer (score 11):

This is about you as a programmer having the chance to boundary check, not whether the compiler can do it.

Just try to print out all the elements in the array, with the size:

```
 void say(int ar[],int sizeAn)
 {
     for(int i=0; i< sizeAn; ++i)
         cout<<ar[i]<<endl;
 }
```

now without the size:

```
 void say(int ar[])
 {
     for(int i=0; i< /*HOW DO I KNOW NOW?*/; ++i)
         cout<<ar[i]<<endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Passing array size as a function parameter is a bad idea, because if you need an array as an array in function passing its size won't have any effect. The array you passed will be decayed to a pointer. So you need to maintain array as is.

Templates provide a simple and effective way to prevent array decay while passing them as function arguments.

```
template<std::size_t N>
void foo(int (&your_array)[N])
{
   for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      //process array, N will be your array size.
}
//simply pass array when calling the function. N be taken automatically.

//somewhere else
int main()
{
  int arr[10];
  foo(arr);
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your code is invoking undefined behavior because you're accessing element 7 of an array that is only 5 elements big. Using the size parameter, you could for instance check if the index is past its size and not do that call instead.

In your example, you get the same results becaue you aren't actually using the parameter:

```
 void say(int ar[],int sizeAn)
 {
     cout<<ar[1]<<endl;
     cout<<ar[7]<<endl;
 }
```

`sizeAn` is unused, so it's not making any difference. But consider for instance the following code:

```
void say(int ar[],int sizeAn)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < sizeAn; i++){
             cout<<ar[i]<<endl;
         }
     }
```

Here, it's printing all the items in the array, so it needs to know how big the array is. If you used an `std::vector`, for instance, you wouldn't need to pass the size as you can just call the `size` function, but you can't do that with C style arrays, so you need to pass that size as a parameter if you want to write a function that behaves differently depending on the size).

Or here's a more practical example of your code where the size parameter is used to avoid the undefined behavior:

```
void say(int ar[],int sizeAn)
 {
     cout<<ar[1]<<endl;
     if (sizeAn >= 8){
         cout<<ar[7]<<endl;
     }
 }
```

Now it's the same as your code with the change that it's only printing the element 7 if it actually exists.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, compilers can't tell how big an array is if passed to a function.  Your first say function tries to reference past the end of the array (ar[7] is beyond the size of 5).  Your second say function means you can length check to make sure you don't make this error.

```
  void say(int ar[], int sizeAn) 
  {
     if(sizeAn>1)
        cout<<ar[1];endl;
     if(sizeAn>7)
        cout<<ar[7];endl;
  }
```

This way, YOU know the length and the function can check it before accessing invalid memory locations.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we specify arrays size as a parameter when passing to function in C++?

Do we?
Well, sometimes. The canonical way to pass a range in C++ is using an iterator-pair though, even if I can see it evolve to using *ranges* when the Range-TS is finally used everywhere.

Anyway, there are other ways to convey what (sub-)range we want to work with. So, let's take a look:

1. In-band-signalling, like `NUL`-terminator for c-strings.
2. An implicit part of the functions contract, like "it will always be exactly 12 elements".
3. Passing a view of the part we want. Unfortunately, until the ranges-TS is fully incorporated, standard-library-support for that is severely anemic, being restricted to `std::string_view` in C++17 and extended with `std::span` for contiguous ranges (like arrays) in C++20 (look at the guideline-support-library for now).
4. Using an iterator-pair. The full flexibility of iterators, though calculating the length might be costly, or impossible without consuming the range. This is the preferred way in the standard-library.
5. Using start-iterator and length. Also quite common, but not to the same degree, and does not allow iterators determining the length as you iterate, not that that is an issue here.
6. Using a (constant where appropriate) reference to the whole container or range, probably templated for generality. This might be combined with point 3, but need not.

Of those, if you know the element-type, and restrict to contiguous arrays, pointer+length is the most comfortable and flexible to use for now, which does not need different code for different lengths, so that's that.